# BufReader in Rust works fine for file, but hangs for serial port

Tags: rust, raspberry-pi, serial-port

Platform: Raspberry Pi Zero W with a [device](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/3686/plantower-pms5003-manual_v2-3.pdf) that continuously transmits data on the Pi's `/dev/ttyS0`.  I have verified this with `cat /dev/ttyS0 | xxd` and can see a stream of data.

```
pi@airq:~ $ cat /dev/ttyS0 | xxd
00000000: 424d 001c 0000 0002 0002 0000 0002 0002  BM..............
00000010: 00ea 0044 001a 0002 0000 0000 9700 0294  ...D............
00000020: 424d 001c 0000 0002 0002 0000 0002 0002  BM..............
00000030: 00ea 0044 001a 0002 0000 0000 9700 0294  ...D............
00000040: 424d 001c 0000 0002 0002 0000 0002 0002  BM..............
00000050: 00ea 0044 001a 0002 0000 0000 9700 0294  ...D............
00000060: 424d 001c 0000 0002 0002 0000 0002 0002  BM..............
00000070: 00fc 0046 001a 0002 0000 0000 9700 02a8  ...F............
```

If capture this output for a second or so with `cat /dev/ttyS0 > test` my program can read (and parse) the data from the file `test`. BUT, if I pass `/dev/ttyS0` to my program, it hangs at BufReader::read.  Here is a snippet of my code:

```
const CHUNK_SIZE: usize = 64;
fn main() {
    let f = File::open('/dev/ttyS0').expect("error opening file");
    let mut reader = BufReader::with_capacity(CHUNK_SIZE, f);

    let mut d: [u8; CHUNK_SIZE] = [0; CHUNK_SIZE];

    let mut h = reader.take(CHUNK_SIZE as u64);
    println!("ready to read");
    let bytes_read = match h.read(&mut d) {
            Ok(n) => n,
            Err(e) => {println!("{:?}", e); 0},
    };

    println!("read ({}): {:?}", bytes_read, d);
 }
```

and the output:

```
pi@airq:~ $ ./airq test
ready to read
read (64): [66, 77, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 156, 0, 48, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 151, 0, 2, 22, 66, 77, 0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 0, 42, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 151, 0, 2, 2]0,0,0
pi@airq:~ $ ./airq /dev/ttyS0
ready to read
^C
pi@airq:~ $
```

Note that the `h.read` call doesn't seem to return.  Not error, not data.. not nuthin...

Comment: `BufReader` will issue a read to the underlying device to fill the whole buffer, which in turn will block until said buffer is filled. If the device does not write enough data, the read will block forever. When reading a file, the end-of-file will short-circuit that, so the call does not block.

Comment: Does it work without `BufReader`? does directly calling `f.read(&mut d)` work?

Comment: Buffered I/O on a serial port is almost always wrong.